# Getting URL variables via javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a url www.myurl.com/angularjs?var=myvar

I am just starting off with AngularJS (and javascript to be honest) and am trying to get the value of 'var' and pass it to my controller but I have no idea how to access the url variables

This is my controller...

```
vdApp.controller('ApplicantCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('http://www.myurl.com/services', iWantToPassMyDataHere).success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.results = data;
    });
}]);
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: This might be helpful. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams
Inject in your controller.. and access by `$routeParams.myVariableName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location)'s `search()` method for that:

```
vdApp.controller('ApplicantCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $http.post('http://www.myurl.com/services', $location.search()).success(function(data) {
        $scope.results = data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response! I've tried that and it's not returning any results. I think it's because it's not passing the parameter to my endpoint. How can I check if it? I've tried setting $scope.myVar = $location.search() and it's just empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`document.location.search` returns the query string from the url

Answer (score 0):

Use `location.search` and split out the query string like this:

```
var queryVals = location.search.split('&');
var v = queryVals[0].split('=')[1];
```

This is assuming that your query parameter, `var`, is the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You get problems with `#` If you don't use regex.

```
var get = getUrlVars();
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    /*Splits the variables into chuncks*/
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
        /*Takes those chunks and removes anything after the hashtag*/
        vars[key] = value.replace(/#\b[^#]*$/gi, '');
    });
    return vars;
}
```

This changes

`http://www.yourdomain.com/account/products/productEdit.php?product_key=2edc8450-e75b-11e4-97c1-d02788bb017c`

to

`get.product_key = '2edc8450-e75b-11e4-97c1-d02788bb017c'`

And

`http://www.yourdomain.com/account/products/productEdit.php?product_key=2edc8450-e75b-11e4-97c1-d02788bb017c#inventory`

to

`get.product_key = '2edc8450-e75b-11e4-97c1-d02788bb017c'`

Use this site to explore regular expressions. http://regexr.com/